# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sdk

Heye guy's,
I've made an SDK which contains 3 modules. 1 = the hypervisor-core, 1 = a hypervisor-converter and 1 = the main sdk hypervisor. The main reason I split the sdk up into 3 modules is to share code among the modules. The core contains shared logics which is implemented inside the converter and the main sdk. I've implemented the core through : compileOnly dependency so it won't get implemented inside the AAR. The only problem I'm facing now is that I can't seem to get them working if i assemble the release aar's. If I assemble them as debug and implement the core, converter and main sdk inside my project it will run fine however when I implement the release AAR's it will actually give me:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDevAppDebugDuplicateClasses'.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.bemobile.hypervisor_core.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-hypervisor-core-release-runtime (:hypervisor-core-release:) and jetified-hypervisor-release-runtime (:hypervisor-release:)
> Duplicate class com.bemobile.hypervisor_core.deserializers.FeatureCollectionDeserializer found in modules jetified-hypervisor-core-release-runtime (:hypervisor-core-release:) and jetified-hypervisor-release-runtime (:hypervisor-release:)  etc.

I don't know how this is happening. I expect the same to happen on debug but it isn't so that's confusing. I'm not an expert on gradle so this is really confusing for me. I've decompiled the AAR's and there is no reference from hypervisor-release -> hypervisor-core-release. There are no classes com.bemobile.hypervisor_core.BuildConfig inside hypervisor. It's only inside the core module. I hope somebody can help me maybe it's something with the compileOnly? I've tried with implementation and Api however the same is happening. But with api and implementation I'm actually seeing the com.bemobile.hypervisor_core inside the hypervisor sdk. So I used compileOnly to not get it included inside the AAR.

I hope somebody can help me through this problem and get it working as release-aar's. In the ideal situation it would be nice to only include Hypervisor.aar and hypervisor-converter.aar in my project to make it work however if it's needed to include hypervisor-core to make it work it's fine too.

my project dependency:

```
implementation(name:'hypervisor-release', ext:'aar')
implementation(name:'hypervisor-converter-release', ext:'aar')
implementation(name:'hypervisor-core-release', ext:'aar')
```

Gradle dependency inside hypervisor:

```
compileOnly project(':hypervisor-core')
```

Decompiled hypervisor-release.aar:
[image: Decompiled hypervisor-release.aar]